# Are teams adopting BDD for regression testing?

Tags: testing, testng, regression, bdd

Have been hearing a lot about BDD with Selenium being adopted for regression testing. Are teams using BDD for writing regression tests? I am asking about automating test cases for a decent consumer based application like a banking app.

Comment: For folks who have down voted. Can you please comment why you down voted so that I can avoid repeating it next time?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is opinioned based. You can use BDD whereever you can formalize behaviour with required style. If you google a little bit your will find examples related to your business domain like this one - https://www.slideshare.net/chrix2/testing-banking-apps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My up-vote is not visible now as my reputation is below 50 points. It should update soon.

Answer (score 0):

One of the benefits of doing BDD well is that you can end up with a suite of automated scenarios that are useful in dealing with regression. However you have to be realistic about what these scenarios provide. The best they can do is say something like

"Its likely that your application is behaving in roughly the same way as it was before you made your changes. Nothing obvious seems broken"

For many applications this is sufficiently empowering to provide great benefits.

What scenarios can never do is 'prove' that your application is working. BDD works best with high level abstract scenarios that mainly cover happy paths. BDD deliberately talks about scenarios not about tests. Scenarios are not tests and are not the sort of things you should try and use to prove that your banking, healthcare or space shuttle software are working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think BDD is one of the approaches to agile development. We have TDD (Test Driven Development), ATDD (Acceptance Test Driven Development) and so many other approaches.

Secondly, you can use any of these approaches with your development and testing. And Yes, can use it with Selenium as well, to write functional UI tests. For this you could use Cucumber BDD plugin if using Java or Calabash BDD plugin if using Ruby (and you have many more BDD plugins). The reason people use BDD is, it makes the requirements clearer as it is in simple Given, When, Then (GWT) English statements. This means non-technical folks can write a test case in GWT statement, and a technical person can then automate these English statements without any ambiguity on what needs to be done.

I personally used Cucumber with Java and Appium, and I found it very helpful. If you are curious about how I did it, you can check out my post here - http://www.rajsubra.com/2017/04/03/appiumjavacucumber-set-up-step-by-step-instructions/

Comment: Hi Raj. _Please_ stop adding signatures/links to posts - thank you! It is enforced by moderators here.